# Is there a way of making FluentValidation stop processing other rules without setting CascadeMode for all rules?

Tags: c#, validation, fluentvalidation

Say I have classes like this :

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public ChildClass Child { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
public class ChildClass
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

And a validator like this :

```
public class ParentClassValidator : AbstractValidator<ParentClass>
{
    public ParentClassValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Child).NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.Date).Must((parent, date) => 
            date < parent.Child.EndDate && date > parent.Child.StartDate);
        // ...other rules.
    }
}
```

Is it possible to tell FluentValidation to stop checking rules if the first one fails (e.g. Child is null), but run all other rules, regardless of failure if that passes?

i.e. I really want something like :

```
public ParentClassValidator()
{
    RuleFor(x => x.Child).NotNull().StopOnFailure();
    RuleFor(x => x.Date).Must((parent, date) => date < parent.Child.EndDate && date > parent.Child.StartDate);
    // ...other rules.
}
```

I know I can set the CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure, but that will make all rule failures terminate checking. To be honest, in this case I just want to save FluentValidation from throwing an exception due to trying to access parent.Child which it already knows to be null!

Comment: For this example, you should be able to use [When](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Customising&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#WhenUnless) although it would require duplicating the not null check between a validation and the when predicate.

Comment: Bleh. That doesn't feel like a very clean way of doing it :( I suspect that's the only way though.

Comment: I suspect this also : see http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/352581

Answer (score -1):

A (not that nice way) to achieve what you want would be to use a not empty ctor

```
public class ParentClassValidator : AbstractValidator<ParentClass>
{
    public ParentClassValidator(bool childIsNotNull)
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Child).NotNull();

    if (childIsNotNull) {
        RuleFor(x => x.Date).Must((parent, date) => 
            date < parent.Child.EndDate && date > parent.Child.StartDate);
        // ...other rules.
    }
}
```

}

then you could use it this way :

```
new ParentClassValidator(model.Child != null).ValidateAndThrow()
```

But it depends on how you're use to call your validator... The "automatic" call (with attributes) won't be possible, you'll have to call the `ValidateAndThrow` "manually", and it somehow breaks the usage of the validator.

Comment: It's hacky but serves the purpose